# How to include the activity in fragment tabs ?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am developing an app in which there are two fragmenttabs.when pressing the tabs corresponding fragments will appear.that works fine.but what I want an activity inside the fragmenttabs. I am using ABS library for this.

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.Tab tab1 = bar.newTab();
        ActionBar.Tab tab2 = bar.newTab();
tab1.setText("Fragment A");
        tab2.setText("Fragment B");
tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener<FragmentA>(this, "tab1",
                FragmentA.class, null));
        tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener<FragmentB>(this, "tab1",
                FragmentB.class, null));
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go Location selection
            Intent intent = new Intent(FragmentDemoActivity.this,
                    TestActivity.class);
             intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
             startActivity(intent);
             return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("tab", getSupportActionBar()
                .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }
```

listnerclass is

```
public class MyTabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private final FragmentActivity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;
    private final Bundle mArgs;
    private Fragment mFragment;

    public MyTabListener(FragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz,
            Bundle args) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
        mArgs = args;

        FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        mFragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                mTag);
        if (mFragment != null && !mFragment.isDetached()) {
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (mFragment == null) {
            mFragment = Fragment
                    .instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(), mArgs);
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
            ft.commit();
        } else {
            ft.attach(mFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (mFragment != null) {
            ft.detach(mFragment);
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Fragmentclass

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    Button button;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle saved)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_b, group, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        button = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Fragment B");
                builder.setMessage("What would you like to do?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Nothing", null);
                builder.setNegativeButton("Leave me alone!", null);
                builder.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

i wnt to include the following activity in the fragmentB

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    Button b1, b2;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testactivity);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv.setText("You Clicked on Button 1");
            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv.setText("You Clicked on Button 2");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I have lot of created activites to  include in the fragment..its un imaginable to recreate in onActivityCreated of fragment class. according to this I have to modify my main application.

Comment: You cannot run an activity inside of a fragment. At best, you can have a fragment inside of a fragment.

Answer (score 6):

A Fragment can't host an activity. Instead of activity, you can use Nested Fragment. 
A simple tutorial: http://xperiment-andro.blogspot.com/2013/02/nested-fragments.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run an activity inside of a fragment. At best, you can have a fragment inside of a fragment.
so the best thing you can do in this situation is instead of creating an `Activity` you can create a `Fragment` and add it inside your `FragmentB`.

Answer (score 1):

Like Faheem Said " 
A Fragment can't host an activity. Instead of activity, you can use Nested Fragment"

Fragments are just like Activities if you read the Docs.Changing your activity to Fragment is easy

This is what **developer.android** says

To create a fragment, you must create a subclass of Fragment (or an existing subclass of it). The Fragment class has code that looks a lot like an Activity. It contains callback methods similar to an activity, such as onCreate(), onStart(), onPause(), and onStop(). **In fact, if you're converting an existing Android application to use fragments, you might simply move code from your activity's callback methods into the respective callback methods of your fragment.**

Usually, you should implement at least the following lifecycle methods:

**onCreate()**
    The system calls this when creating the fragment. Within your implementation, you should initialize essential components of the fragment that you want to retain when the fragment is paused or stopped, then resumed.

**onCreateView()**
    The system calls this when it's time for the fragment to draw its user interface for the first time. To draw a UI for your fragment, you must return a View from this method that is the root of your fragment's layout. You can return null if the fragment does not provide a UI.

**onPause()**
    The system calls this method as the first indication that the user is leaving the fragment (though it does not always mean the fragment is being destroyed). This is usually where you should commit any changes that should be persisted beyond the current user session (because the user might not come back).

Answer (score 0):

This is the code activity inside Fragment.

YourActivityName.getSupportFragmentManager();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).